# Shunting yard algorithm with handling unary NOT operator in Ternary string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am currently writing a Infix to Prefix transfer of a Ternary logic string. In specific, there are only three operands T,F,U and three operators AND, NOT, OR and brackets in the string. Not has higher precedence than AND, OR and AND OR have same precedence. Here's my code changing from original shunting yard algorithm but the translation is not correct for some input

```
string Infix_To_Prefix(string expression){
    string prefix_expression = "";
    stack<char> char_stack;
    unordered_map<char,int> Precendence;
    Precendence['~'] = 2;
    Precendence['|'] = 1;
    Precendence['&'] = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<expression.size();i++)
    {
        char token = expression[i];
        if(isOperator(token))
        {
            while(!char_stack.empty() and isOperator(char_stack.top()))
            {
                if(Precendence[token] < Precendence[char_stack.top()])
                {
                    prefix_expression+=char_stack.top();
                    char_stack.pop();
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            char_stack.push(token);
        }

        else if(token == '(')
        {
            char_stack.push(token);
        }
        else if(token == ')')
        {
            while(!char_stack.empty() and char_stack.top() != '(')
            {
                prefix_expression+=char_stack.top();
                char_stack.pop();
            }
            char_stack.pop();
        }
        else if(isOperand(token))
        {
            prefix_expression+=token;
        }

    }
    while(!char_stack.empty())
    {
        prefix_expression+=char_stack.top();;
        char_stack.pop();
    }
    return prefix_expression;
}
```

Comment: There is no ternary operator in that question. There is also no indication of where you got the "original shunting yard algorithm" from, and it would probably be a good idea to provide a reference.

Comment: http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/

Comment: And what input, exactly, produces what error?

Comment: Input will be ~(T|F&~(U|T))  the output should be TF|UT|~&~ this kind of thing. The output from this algorithm is not exactly the prefix expression of input in some situation.

Comment: The expression `~(T|F&~(U|T))`  produces the output `TFUT|~&|~`, in which the `~` operators apply precisely as specified. Your problem is that the associativity of `&` and `|` is not as you expect. So I think you should rephrase your question.

Comment: OK. So I think my program output correctly if it is TFUT|~&|~ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you check the precedence:

```
if(Precendence[token] < Precendence[char_stack.top()])
{
    prefix_expression+=char_stack.top();
    char_stack.pop();
    continue;
}
```

In the program you cited in a comment, which is certainly not the original Shunting Yard implementation, the code is

```
if ((isAssociative(token, LEFT_ASSOC) && 
        cmpPrecedence(token, stack.peek()) <= 0) || 
    (isAssociative(token, RIGHT_ASSOC) && 
        cmpPrecedence(token, stack.peek()) < 0)) 
{
    out.add(stack.pop());   
    continue;
}
```

So your test is the same as what the provided code does in the case of *right-associative* operators, and that is what your code does. If you want your operators to be left-associative, you would need to change the `<` to `<=`, as in the code you are adapting.

However, that won't work in the case of unary operators, because unary operators need to be right-associative, at least in the simplistic view normally shown in implementations of the shunting yard algorithm.

It would be more accurate to say that a unary operator should always be pushed onto the stack regardless of the precedence of the operator which precedes it; since it does not take a right-hand operator, it is not competing with the preceding operator, only with the following one. So a unary operator as an incoming token must have higher precedence than any operator on the stack, although a unary operator on the stack may or may not have higher precedence than incoming operator tokens. If the unary operator is the highest-precedence operator, then making it right-associative will have that effect. So I think it is cleaner to special-case unary operators, as you already do with parentheses:

```
for (char token: expression)  {
  if (token == '(' || token == '~')
    char_stack.push(token);
  else if (isOperator(token)) {
    while (!char_stack.empty()
           and isOperator(char_stack.top())
           and Precendence[token] < Precendence[char_stack.top()]) {
        prefix_expression+=char_stack.top();
        char_stack.pop();
    }
    char_stack.push(token);
  }
  else if(token == ')') {
    while(!char_stack.empty() and char_stack.top() != '(') {
      prefix_expression+=char_stack.top();
      char_stack.pop();
    }
    char_stack.pop();
  }
  else if(isOperand(token))
    prefix_expression+=token;
}
```

The similarity between the various loops which pop the stacks should suggest a simplification, which is usually implemented in operator-precedence parsers (of which the Shunting Yard is an example).

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that but when I change to <=, I find the output is also incorrect. The input is ~~~~~(T|F)|F but the output is ~~TF|~~~F

Comment: @庄祎炜: Good point. You need to handle the unary operator differently. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I think it works correctly now!